# 3 urns; numbered balls; pick urn, draw 2 balls no replacement.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

i've been struggling with this one for a while now...

we've got 3 urns: A,B,C

A - 10 numbered {1,..,10} white balls.

B - 5 numbered {1,..,5} red balls.

C - 15 numbered {1,..,15} blue balls.

**Pick an urn (each urn is p=1/3) and draw 2 balls out of it without replacement.**

**X - number of odd numbers drawn**

**question is, what kind of distribution are we talking about?**

given 4 possible answers: binomial, geometric, hypergeometric, and none of the answers is true.

marked off the first two as we have no replacement.

it sounds like it's hypergeomteric, but the population N and the special type K (odd numbers) changes in size depending on the urn we picked.

A : N=10 K=5,

B : N=5 K=3,

C : N=15 K=8

if it is hypergeometric, N=? K=?

thanks in advance..

Comment: You are correct that for each urn, the number of odd numbers drawn follows a hypergeometric distribution. But now you are mixing the 3 different urns, so you get a mixture of 3 different hypergeometric distributions, which in general will not be a hypergeometric distribution anymore.

Comment: the following question asks E(X)'s value with 4 options:

25, 25/3, 25/45, 49/45

and if i try calculating the mean regularly (sum of xP(x)), i never seem to get it right for some reason.

Comment: For hypergeometric distribution, once you have proved the formula for mean once, you should use apply it every time afterward. No need to do the summation again. And the mean of a mixture distribution again is the weighted average of the individual means (you may refer to wiki) following from the law of total expectation